# Create a basic application that will act as a tutorial for how to use another app

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a very particular application I have developed.  I want to create a second app, ideally in visual basic, that provides a tutorial/ guide on how to use my original app step by step.

I imagine PowerPoint slide style images embedded in a simple window with forward & back controls.

I have experience in java, C & VB.  Ideally the app needs be be kept simple and written in VB.  Can anyone recommend a starting point, or if any tutorials for such exist?  I've had a search and nothing stands out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

So, if this essentially just has slides and annotations and forward/backward buttons, why try to write an app for this?  (I *get* that it might be fun to try.)  You could simply do screen captures and annotate them and use PowerPoint and create an executable out of that to run.

You can even, I understand, create hyperlinks and such to allow the slide show to progress more like the real app does.  I'm no "power point ranger" so I'd point you at the Office docs to learn about that, but I've seen some pretty good tutorials using this method.

Comment: Hi itsmatt.  Yeah, I was thinking screen grabs of powerpoint and something like this --> http://i.imgur.com/DRamA.jpg  Have not used VB in many years, so my programming is very rusty unfortunately!

Comment: Yep, you could certainly do something like that.  Powerpoint would be the easiest thing here, I think.  A bit tedious, perhaps, to take all the screen shots but I suspect there are apps out there that can streamline that too.  Good Luck!

Comment: I have this behind my next button code: 
        picbox.Image = My.Resources.pic1

        picbox.Image = My.Resources.pic2    it always loads the pic2 & never the first.  I need to add logic that allows each click to cycle through the images?